# Git применение изменений

Tags: git, git-branch

Есть основая ветка `(master)` и есть ветка, которая от нее когда то наследовалась `(design)`. Так же эта ветка лежит на remote стороне.

После в мастер мержились коммиты (из других веток). И в ветку `design` комитились и пушились изменения.

Визуально выглядит примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Красная линия** - мастер, **зеленая** - design

Я хочу, чтобы в ветке `desing` были все изменения, сделанные в мастере. ( после комита `design3` были все изменения из `master6`)

Делаю следующее :

```
git checkout design // она же указывает на origin/desing
git pull origin master
```

И после этого мне предлагает смержить ветки, и после при пуше у меня есть комиты, которые были сделаны в ветке мастер.

Как мне применить все измениния из мастера в `desing`? ( при этом не хочется комитить те комиты, которые были в мастере. Или это нереально?)

Comment: Так вы хотите или не хотите коммиты из master в design? Предпоследнее предложение соткано из противоречий.

Comment: @free_ze Я хочу обновить ветку desing до состояния последнего комита из мастера. Если я сделаю так, как описал в вопросе, то при пуше у меня будут комиты из мастера.

Comment: Cостояние master состоит из коммитов, почему вас это смущает? Отслеживаемая история изменений - это классно. Но если вам это не нужно, то попробуйте сделать rebase.

Comment: думаю, что Вам нужно такое

`git pull && git checkout design && git rebase master design`

Comment: @KoVadim это делать в ветке master?

Comment: посмотрите внимательно. я там явно переключаю ветку. Поэтому не имеет значения (ну почти). Предупреждение - эта штука сделает так, что ветка desing будет как будто только что ответвилась от самого свежего мастера.

Comment: @KoVadim, лучше `git rebase --onto master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите в коммите **design3** иметь все изменения ветки **master**, то после объединения веток Вы не сможете через `git push` отправить на удалённый репозиторий коммиты только **design** или только **master**.

Чтобы все изменения из **master** были в ветке **design**, Вам нужно сначала переключиться в ветку **design**:

```
git checkout design
```

Затем, выполнить перемещение:

```
git rebase master
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но я все таки мержил мастер в дезайн и пушил в уже удаленную ветку дезайн. Потом ( я надеюсь) смогу нормально смержить дизайн в мастер

Comment: @AndrewBystrov На будущее: старайтесь в качестве основной ветки пользоваться master. Это же ветка обычно используется для релизов или продакшна.

Comment: @macishOk дело в том, что ветка дезайн - это параллельная ветка, которая долго живет. Как только там будет все сделано, она будет смержена в мастер. Просто хочется заранее мастер мержить в дезайн, чтобы было меньше конфликтов в будущем.